# WakeUp Feature on BeagleBone Black Debian OS

Tags: debian, embedded, beagleboneblack, gpio, wakeup

I want to use the wakeup GPIO feature of my BeagleBone Black Rev C with the 4.4.29 kernel

The OMAP Driver is loaded and i am also able to interact with the GPIOs (direction, value..). 
Somehow the folder for using the wakeup feature is missing
(/sys/class/gpio/gpioX/power/wakeup)

I tried to modify the gpio-omap.c file in the kernel files, but i had no success.

Does anyone know how to proceed here?

Comment: Please help us to help you by defining "no success." How have you modified the kernel files?

Comment: This didn't enable the wakeup features, so i reverted it. I read in the internet that the initialization of the pinmux has a bug, but was not able to solve it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need the same thing :)

Comment: Hi Davide, unfortunately i didn't continue on this topic since the project is delayed. But since i didnt find anything I was about to enable the wakeup on the GPIO0 Port (only port where it is possible) with a kernel module and enable the feature directly via writing to the processor's registers